# javascript to remove dynamically added div

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 3 textfield which i want to clone with one remove icon on add button click ...upto this my code works fine.

Now i want to remove the last 3 textfields of that particular div on remove button click...but my code removes all the dynamically added textfields of my form..

please help me to resolve this....

```js
$('#add_exercise').on('click', function() {
  $('#exercises').append('<div class="exercise"><input type="text" name="exercise[]"></div>');
  $('#exercises').append('<div class="exercise"><input type="text" name="exercise[]"></div>');
  $('#exercises').append('<div class="exercise"><input type="text" name="exercise[]"><button class="remove">x</button></div>');
  return false;
});

$('#exercises').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).parents("#exercises").remove();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="exercises">
  <div class="exercise">
    <input type="text" name="exercise[]">
    <input type="text" name="exercise[]">
    <input type="text" name="exercise[]">
  </div>
  <button id="add_exercise">add exercise</button>
  <button class="remove">x</button>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: check your class and id sign, instead .exercise you are saying to remove entire fieldset which holds #exercises

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is with your use of `.parents('#excercises')` as this selects the top level container and removes it.

A better solution would be to wrap all the 3 inputs you append in their own div and then remove that using `closest()`, like this:

```js
$('#add_exercise').on('click', function() {
  $('#exercises').append('<div class="exercise"><input type="text" name="exercise[]"><input type="text" name="exercise[]"><input type="text" name="exercise[]"><button type="button" class="remove">x</button></div>');
});

$('#exercises').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).closest(".exercise").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="exercises">
  <div class="exercise">
    <input type="text" name="exercise[]">
    <input type="text" name="exercise[]">
    <input type="text" name="exercise[]">
    <button type="button" class="remove">x</button>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="add_exercise">add exercise</button>
</fieldset>
```

Note that I added `type="button"` to your `<button>` elements as it would make sense for them not to submit any parent `form` elements.

Comment: $('div.exercise').children().remove();

Comment: @DevlshOne I don't see your point - that would again remove all excercises instead of only the clicked one

Comment: Typing too fast! `$('div.exercise').children().last().remove();`